# Error to add android folder to Ionic project using capacitor

Tags: android, angular, npm, ionic-framework, capacitor

I updated my capacitor packages to 5 like this :

```
"@capacitor/android": "^5.0.4",
    "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^5.0.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.2",
```

When I run : ionic cap add android to add the android folder to my ionic project I get :

```
npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/android@4.1.0
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: sukssas@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @capacitor/core@5.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/core
npm ERR!   @capacitor/core@"^5.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @capacitor/core@"^4.0.0" from @capacitor/android@4.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@capacitor/android
npm ERR!   @capacitor/android@"4.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

    npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/android@4.1.0 exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I don't know why `npm run : npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/android@4.1.0` while I already upgraded to  `@capacitor/android`, I tried to remove node_modules and do `npm install` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by migrating correctly to capacitor 5:

```
> npm i -D @capacitor/cli@latest
```

```
> npx cap migrate
```

source : https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/5-0